# How do I show and start animating a UIActivityIndicatorView from within a method

Tags: iphone, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a method that does a time consuming operation, say something like ten consecutive calls to 
[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:u];

I want a UIActivityIndicatorView that was in a hidden state before the method call to show and animate, so I write:

```
activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

at the beginning of the method

but of course it won't work.  The UIActivityIndicatorView will only animate once the method is over.

This is not acceptable.  I must show the animation during the function call.

Anyone knows how to do it?

NSOperation maybe? (anyone has a sample thereof?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are doing some expensive work in this method and while that work is being performed, you want the activity indicator to spin. Expensive work should **NOT** be done on the main thread (iOS might kill your app!). Put your expensive work on a separate thread with:

```
- (void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg
```

...and when the method (aSelector) is done, call:

```
- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait
```

...and there you stop the activity indicator.

Never call any UI code from within a non-main thread!