# UIActivityIndicatorView only appears after loading finishes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

In my UITableView I'm using custom cells with a book title, book status and renew button. However, book status requires some loading view internet and therefore takes time to load.

Have tried doing Asynchronous to load only the part on the book status but it's too hard. Therefore, I was trying to do a "Loading Data" spinner instead. Had created a class for spinner and implemented in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but the spinner only shows at the end when my UITable had already finish all the loading! I have no idea where to place this codes:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    lVC = [[LoadingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoadingViewiPad" bundle:nil];
    [self.parentViewController.view addSubview:lVC.view];
} else {
    lVC = [[LoadingViewController alloc] init];
    [self.parentViewController.view addSubview:lVC.view];
}
```

I have already tried placing it in `viewDidLoad` and even `viewWillAppear` but it just don't seemed to work. The results of all just ends up that the spinner shows up at the end when all things had already finish loading.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UserCustomCell *cell = (UserCustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UserCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = userCustomCell;
    self.userCustomCell = nil;
}

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    cell.bookTitle.frame = CGRectMake(12, 0, 550, 40);
    cell.renewButton.frame = CGRectMake(600, 14, 68, 24);
}
[cell.renewButton useBlackActionSheetStyle];

cell.bookTitle.text =@"Book Title";

// I place the UIActivityIndicator class here before I do the loading
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    lVC = [[LoadingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoadingViewiPad" bundle:nil];
    [self.parentViewController.view addSubview:lVC.view];
} else {
    lVC = [[LoadingViewController alloc] init];
    [self.parentViewController.view addSubview:lVC.view];
}
NSString *reservation = [self noOfRenewalLeft:index];   ###### throw into method to do internet connection and checking
                                                                                                //method will then return NSString "reserved" or "notReserved"

if ([reservation isEqualToString: @"notReserved"]){     //if item not reserved

    if([renewalLeftString isEqualToString: @"0"]){              
        cell.bookStatus.text = @"Reached Max Renewal Limit";
    }
    else{                                                   //item not reserved & able to renew, therefore display renewal left
        cell.bookStatus.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Renewal Left: %@",renewalLeftString];
    }
}
else {
    cell.bookStatus.text = @"Item Reserved/On-Hold";
}

cell.renewButton.tag = index_tag;
return cell;
```

}

Comment: can you show more code where you put the above line of code and where you load you send request?

Comment: Place your UIActivityIndicator before you load anything....and remove it when your loading finished...

Comment: @CocoaMatters It's updated! :) I did put in the UIActivityIndicator before I do my loading in my other noOfRenewalLeft method

Comment: I did place it before I do loading. For testing purpose I did not remove it as if i remove it, the indicator does not even shows up. Right now it shows after the UITable has finish loading everything.

Comment: where are you placing ActivityIndicator ?

Comment: are you doing an asynchronous connection to the Internet? If not, your UIActivityIndicatorView will show only after the download is completed. See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317068/how-do-i-show-and-start-animating-a-uiactivityindicatorview-from-within-a-method) helps.

Comment: @Rick ya I'm not doing asynchronous connection as it looks pretty hard and i can't understand the examples found. Like the link you gave, the answer to the question is to use - (void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg to perform the loading in a separate thread. But I do not understand how to use it

Comment: You can choose either to show your noOfRenewalLeft method and see if anyone here can help or instead of showing an activity indicator, just display a text "loading status..." without animation, clear it after download is completed.

Comment: Here's a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial) to help you understand the concept of Grand Central Dispatch and updating UI while downloading data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end what I did was to place the UIActivityIndicator in the viewDidLoad method instead, and cancelled it in viewDidAppear. It works now! Thank you everyone for your help too :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the default Apple ActivityIndicator and put it in the Cell. You do not need a class for it.
Then create a Notification when you have finished loading or a delegate method which will be called, when loading is finished. This method then removes the spinner and puts the correct content in the cell. After that refresh the cells which have finished loading and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Event though you didm't post the details of `noOfRenewalLeft` I assume It's loading in the main thread and by that blocking it. So your activity indicator cannot be rendered before the main thread continues (after finishing the download). Try asynchronous download and delegation.

Answer (score 0):

Create individual method and call that method using performselectorinbackground to load activity indicator because loading anything from internet as load in main thread so activity indicator load once download process done.